# Python background worker for RabbitMQ

Tags: python, python-3.x, rabbitmq, backgroundworker

I am building a Python 3 application that will consume messages from RabbitMQ. Is there some Python background job library that can make this easy? I am looking for something similar to [Sneakers](http://jondot.github.io/sneakers/) in Ruby. I would like library to have:

- easy way to define tasks that process RabbitMQ messages (I have a separate non-Python producer application that will create messages and put them into RabbitMQ)
- configure number of worker processes that run
  tasks
- run workers as daemonized processes

Comment: did you check `amqp` package?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're looking for [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/)

You'll define task as follows

```
@task
def mytask(param):
    return 1 + 1
```

It will be put in message broker (for example mentioned RabbitMQ), and then consumed and executed from celery

You can configure number of workers

```
celery worker --concurrency=10
```

And yes, it can be demonized

Comment: Can I configure Celery to run a task whenever message is added to the queue? I have a separate non-Python producer application that will create messages and put them into RabbitMQ

Comment: Yes, sure, it is default case. Though i never tried to put tasks in queue from non-python producer.
As an additional case you can run tasks periodically (like a cron), run them with some delay etc

Comment: I’ve put tasks into the queue from an iOS app using librabbitmq. As long as you follow the task format (http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/internals/protocol.html) it will just work.

Answer (score 1):

To consume task of RabbitMq you have to define worker, but to run worker in  a daemonized mode you have to create a supervisor for that worker

- command to start worker

  - `celery worker --concurrency=10 -Ofair --loglevel=DEBUG -A file_name_without_extension -Q queue_name`
- steps to create supervisor

  - https://thomassileo.name/blog/2012/08/20/how-to-keep-celery-running-with-supervisor/
  - http://python-rq.org/patterns/supervisor/